# Retrieving parameters passed in the url and returning the value in the web browser using restlet

Tags: eclipse-indigo, restlet-2.0

I need help in retrieving the parameters passed when the user types in the url as  http://localhost:8182/trace/abc/def?param=123  where the parameter passed is 123. How do i get the 123 displayed on the web browser.Which java classes should i change in order to retrieve and return the parameters in the web page

Here are the codes that i have:

```
Part05
import org.restlet.Component;
//import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;


public class Part05 extends ServerResource {  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        // Create the HTTP server and listen on port 8182  
        //new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, Part05.class).start(); 

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        // Create a new Restlet component and add a HTTP server connector to it  
        Component component = new Component();  
        component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);  

        // Then attach it to the local host  
        component.getDefaultHost().attach("/trace", Part05.class);  

        // Now, let's start the component!  
        // Note that the HTTP server connector is also automatically started.  
        component.start();  
    }  
    @Get  
    public String toString() {  

        // Print the requested URI path  
        return "Resource URI  : " + getReference() + '\n' + "Root URI      : "  
                + getRootRef() + '\n' + "Routed part   : "  
                + getReference().getBaseRef() + '\n' + "Remaining part: "  
                + getReference().getRemainingPart() ;
    } }
```

Main

```
import org.restlet.Component;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            // Create a new Restlet component and add a HTTP server connector to it  
            Component component = new Component();  
            component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);  

            // Then attach it to the local host  
            component.getDefaultHost().attach("/trace", Part05.class);  

            // Now, let's start the component!  
            // Note that the HTTP server connector is also automatically started.  
            component.start();  
    }}
```

Output that i got:
Resource URI  : http://localhost:8182/trace/abc/def?param=123
Remaining part: /abc/def?param=123

Help is needed urgently!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the Restlet Documentation and [online help](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/330-restlet/58-restlet.html)

Here's how you can access the parameters within the `@Get` method of the `ServerResource` class: (Example borrowed from the documentation link above)

```
Form form = request.getResourceRef().getQueryAsForm();
for (Parameter parameter : form) {
  System.out.print("parameter " + parameter.getName());
  System.out.println("/" + parameter.getValue());
}
```

You can just return a string representation of the parameter's value (i.e. `123` in your case).

You can get the entire query string (as a `String`) if you instead say:

`request.getResourceRef().getQuery(); // or getQuery(true) if you wish to have URI decoding`

But you'll have to parse if for the values yourself in that case. The former is better since it does that for you and gives you access to a Parameter List :)

These are explained in the Javadocs